# No idea why my code isn't working

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

```
month = (input('Enter the month (first 3 letters): '))
if month == ('Dec' or 'Jan' or 'Feb'):
    season = ('Summer')     
elif month == ('Mar' or 'Apr' or 'May'):
    season = ('Autumn')
elif month == ('Jun' or 'Jul' or 'Aug'):
    season = ('Winter')
elif month == ('Sep' or 'Oct' or 'Nov'):
    season = ('Spring')
else:
    season = ('not real') 
print('The month of',month,'is',season,)
```

I don't know why this isn't working. 
It came back saying season isn't defined.
It works for the first result of each. Dec, Mar, Jun, Sep for example.
Help please :)

Comment: I have an idea... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-do-i-test-one-variable-against-multiple-values

Comment: Open a Python prompt, enter `('Dec' or 'Jan' or 'Feb')`, press Enter and you might get an idea.

Comment: And BTW: mapping values to other values is best done with a dictionary.

Comment: And another BTW: You have a "parentheses overflow". `season = 'Summer'` is enough, there's no need to write `season = ('Summer')`.